# PHP or JS regex to parse javascript functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So this is similar to my last question, but I made some progress. I have a script that will gather all javascript on the page and post it to a php page. I wanted to at some point start parsing the data for functions declaration and usage, but I am getting a ton of errors when trying. Here is what I have to start:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
var file, S =0;
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
function saveJS(JS, FILE){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/concat.php",
    data: {
      scriptText: JS,
      file: FILE
    },
    success: function(response) { }
  });
}   
function getJS(FILE){
    var response;
    $.get( FILE, function( data ) {
        saveJS(data, FILE)
    });

}

function postLoop () {          
   setTimeout(function () {   
      if (S < scripts.length) {          
        if (scripts[S].src) {
            getJS(scripts[S].src)
        }else{
            saveJS(scripts[S].innerHTML, "inline");
        }       
      S++;            
      postLoop();            
      }      
   }, 4000)
}
postLoop();
});  
</script>

<?php
$file = 'scripts.js';
$JS = $_REQUEST["scriptText"];
$contents = "

// Source File: " . $_REQUEST["file"] . "   //

" . $JS ."

// End File: " . $_REQUEST["file"] . "   //

";
preg_replace("#([\n\r]{1,2})#", "\r\n", $contents);
file_put_contents($file, $contents, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

This will generate a single .js file that has every line of javascript code - whether written inline or pulled in from a remote .js file. As you would expect, there will be a mixture of single and double quotes and maybe even a backtick here and there which means there would probably need to be some HTML Special Chars escaping or something.

Using PHP I haven't been able to figure out any way to use this regular expression:

```
function.*\(.*\).*\{(.|\n)*?\n\}
```

I have tried using things like:

```
preg_match_all(function.*\(.*\).*\{(.|\n)*?\n\}, $contents,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($out);

preg_match_all('function.*\(.*\).*\{(.|\n)*?\n\}', $contents,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($out);

$matches = array();
preg_match(`function.*\(.*\).*\{(.|\n)*?\n\}`, $contents, $matches);
print_r($matches);

$split = preg_split("function.*\(.*\).*\{(.|\n)*?\n\}", $contents);
print_r($split);
```

None of those return any results, so I tried similar things in Javascript and came up empty. My final file is about 2.5Mb, so I was thinking PHP would be better, any tips?

Comment: Parsing JavaScript with regex? Good luck with that as JS is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and it is mathematically impossible to do so.

Comment: I could swear it's impossible. How about: `function() { return "}"; }` and `function () { return "\""; }`, `function ( a = ")" ) { }`...

Comment: Thanks guys, the regex `function.*\(.*\).*\{(.|\n)*?\n\}` works great in Sublime and Editplus, I didn't think it would be impossible with PHP since essentially that is what minifiers and uglifiers do, right?

Comment: In my opinion, the best chance to parse the code properly would be to run a full customized JS interpreter that then returns a list of all functions and variables created. Of course, that probably isn't overly feasible. 

Anyway, as I recall, in PHP you will need `preg_whatever("/function.*...your pattern.../", ...);` The important thing is putting starting and closing characters at the beginning and end of the pattern for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for too long, I got something to start working. It matches some stuff I wish it wouldn't, but in the end I think I can work around it since it ends up with null results later.

Here is the PHP

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devongovett/regexgen/master/src/regex.js'); 
$regex = "/((function\s.*\(.*\)\s)?({(?:[^\{\}]++|(?R))*\}))/";
preg_match_all($regex, $html, $tmps, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
// here you could dump $tmps to see what it matches
echo "<pre>";

foreach($tmps[0] as $line){
$regex2 = "/function\s(.*)\(.*\)/";
preg_match_all($regex2, $line, $tmps2);

var_dump($tmps2[1]);
}
echo "</pre>";
```

That will pull up a JS file and bring back the function names:

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "toRegex"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "star"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "union"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "removeCommonSubstring"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "commonSubstring"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "concat"
}
```

Of course there is much more you could do with it, but this will give me a good start on my project.